# how to check the number of clicks the user clicks on an image in swift

Tags: swift

Is there a function to count the numbers of click that the user clicks on an image and when the user starts clicking on another image the count resets.
Like for example : there is an image that requires the user to click on it for 3 times , then another image comes out that requires the user to click on it for 5 times , is there a function that can help me in the touchBegan method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and add one to all the image views you need. As selector you can choose the same method for every gesture recognizer. When the user press in the method you increase the counter and save the view that has received the tap, if the user change the view you can find a mismatch between the previous view and the pressed one. In this case you reset the couter.